# How can I reverse my breaker box cover panel ? Opens the wrong direction

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, subpanel

I have a square D load center - HOMC12UC.  You can install it with the door opening in either direction, since there are identical punchouts in the top and bottom.

However, my installer wasn't thinking and installed it the wrong direction.  So now the default door that came with it is opening the wrong direction (and is difficult to use/access).

You can't just spin the panel cover 180 degrees - it is asymmetrical, vertically.

So, I need the part number for the panel cover that opens the other direction.

Does anyone know that part number ?  I cannot find it.

Comment: https://www.se.com/us/en/download/document/1100CT0501/

Comment: While a very valid question, this boils down to shopping advice which is off-topic. VtC.

Comment: Can you get us the actual part number off the label on the inside of the breaker box?

Comment: Why not put in slot covers and flip it? There will be some spaces with a black plastic slot cover and the main. That’s what I would do. Although it is a shopping question and is off topic that would be a way to fix it.

Comment: This panel cover has a main/primary breaker in it, and we actually have a primary breaker installed, so ... we can't flip it.  Also, as I said, it is asymmetrical - you have to choose the direction you want it to go when you install the panel itself.  That's why I need the opposite opening panel cover now.

Comment: @user227963 -- can you get us photos of the panel itself? We might be able to reverse-engineer it from there...